# ionic3 - AdMobFree - duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest

Tags: android, ionic3, admob, android-manifest

I'm trying to build an ionic3 app in android version..in ios build everything is well an work fine, but when I try `ionic cordova build android` this error is showed:

[image: error showed image]

this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.splitlabs.eggTap" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-66125600censored/censored" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-66125600censored~censored" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

this is my "ionic info"

[image: ionic info screen]

Is 3 days that I'm trying to solve this problem but I didn't find a fix :/ I think the problem is adMobFree plugin but I have no idea what change!

Answer (score 1):

I also got that error. After checking, i saw i installed Admob Plus plugin and Admob Free plugin. So i removed Admob Plus plugin : problem solved. Now only one  is created so no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I had two values for this setting `xml": "<meta-data android:name=\"com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID` for that plugin `admob-plus-cordova` declared twice in `android.json`.

It caused to create more than 1 meta config in `AndroidManifest.xml`, something like `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-xxx~yyy"/>`.

Removing that duplication in `android.json`, and the old metas in `AndroidManifest.xml` caused proper generation of meta in `AndroidManifest.xml` with successful build, which solved my problem.